# disable multi configured webpack parallel build

Tags: webpack

As we tested and see, when we config our webpack to handle multiple entries, `webpack` will run both in parallel way.
But if we need first config output to use in second part what should we do?

If we have some config like this :

```js
module.exports = [
    {
        mode: 'production',
        entry: "./src/workbox-sw.ts",
        output: {
            filename: "workbox-sw.js",
            path: __dirname + "/build"
        },
    }, {
        entry: "./src/public/app.ts",
        output: {
            filename: "app.js",
            path: __dirname + "/build/public"
        },
        target: "web",
        plugins: [
            new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
                swSrc: __dirname + '/build/workbox-sw.js'),
                swDest: 'sw.js',
                exclude: [
                    /\.map$/,
                    /manifest$/,
                    /\.htaccess$/,
                    /service-worker\.js$/,
                    /sw\.js$/,
                ],
            }),
        ],
    }
]
```

is there a way to run first job then do second?

with some config like this, I got module not found error:

```sh
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/project/build/workbox-sw.js' in '/project'
```